# JavaScript serializeToString() Adding Attribute Automatically

Tags: javascript, object, dom

I have the following HTML code which I convert to a document object then a string again using serializeToString():

```js
    let html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <title>Title</title>
     </head>
     <body>Hello
     </body>
    </html>`;
    
    let newHTMLDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString( html, 'text/html' );
    
    let head = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(newHTMLDocument.head);
    
    console.log(head);
```

Why does head contain:

```
<head xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
```

As you can see, the xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" is not in the original string, so why is serializeToString() adding this to my head tag and how can I stop the function from doing that, so the head variable contains this instead:

```
<head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
```

Comment: The DOM parser I'm assuming. It's just correcting the HTML on parse. I can almost guarantee you if you change the HTML type to HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` it won't do that.

Comment: @TyQ. It still does it! I tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [XHTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/), section 3.1.1:

> The root element of the document must contain an xmlns declaration for
>   the XHTML namespace [XMLNS]. The namespace for XHTML is defined to be
>   http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml. An example root element might look like: 
>   `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">`

So, it's just complying with standards.

To convert to text without the serializer maybe something like:

```js
let html = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Title</title>
 </head>
 <body>Hello
 </body>
</html>`;

let newHTMLDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString( html, 'text/html' );

console.log(newHTMLDocument.head.outerHTML);
```

Comment: Good info. Is there a way to turn it off? I don't need it because I'll be inserting that attribute manually in the html tag.

Comment: @GTSJoe see the edit. you can use `outerHTML` in most cases

Comment: This is better than what I was looking for since I don't need to use a function to parse the code. Thank you!